# How to find data with timestamp larger than a certain date time in SQL DBeaver?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I am using DBeaver to track a database using the following query.  It returns me the following error:

> SQL Error [1]: Query failed (#20210308_222034_93358_9bhns): line 22:5: Column 'datatime' cannot be resolved

Does anyone know an easy way for query data larger than a certain datetime (e.g. datetime > '2021-02-01 00:00:00')?

Here is the query:

```
select
    timestamp,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp / 1000) as datatime,
    subscription_name,
    path,
    value
from
    xx.xxxx
where
    subscription_name = 'xx_xx_xx'
    and path in (xxx)
    and datatime > '2021-02-01 00:00:00'
```

Comment: `2021-02-01 00:00:00` needs surrounding quotes, like `'2021-02-01 00:00:00'`.

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This is a SQL server.

Comment: @jarlh Thanks for the catch. It does not work with the quotations either. I updated the question.

Comment: @eshirvana This is a SQL server.

Comment: `and FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp / 1000)  > '2021-02-01 00:00:00'`, since the WHERE clause is evaluated before the column alias is created.

Comment: @jarlh I think we are very close. I tried the following:

`and FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp/1000) > '2021-02-01 15:57:17'`

and still get the following error:

_SQL Error [1]: Query failed (#20210308_230942_00157_9bhns): line 22:35: '>' cannot be applied to timestamp, varchar(19)_

It is very strange since if I try the following"

`and timestamp > 1000`

the query works just fine and it does not have any problem using '>' with timestamp.

Comment: @eshirvana Please see the following for more info on the fomat for datetime used in this query -->    https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-from_unixtime-function.php

Comment: I have tried the following and it work fine:

`and FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp/1000) > current_date - interval '1' day `

Comment: So far, I have found the following band-aid that works with it giving me data after a certain date. But it does not let me narrow down the time window. Any ideas on how to make it narrow down based on date and time together?

`and FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp/1000) >= date('2021-03-05')`  


Essentially, it seems like the FROM_UNTXTIME() output is a datatime format, and not a string format. So perhaps if we can convert the string to datetime format, the problem could be solved. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I also found a better method of doing this so we can control at the time level on Presto SQL:

```
select 
timestamp,
cast(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp/1000) as varchar) as datatime,
subscription_name,
path,
value,
sys_load_dt
        
from xx.xxx
where subscription_name='xx_xx_xx'
and path in(xxx)   
         
and cast(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp/1000) as varchar) >= ('2021-03-05 14:18:00.000')
and cast(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp/1000) as varchar) < ('2021-03-05 15:18:00.000')
```

The only remaining issue is that when we run this query, after fetching about 37000 line it returns the following error:

> Task execution failed
>
> Reason:
> SQL Error [16777220]: Query failed (#20210311_001034_01263_9bhns): Partition location does not exist: hdfs://hdfs-batch/data/xx/xx.xxx/sys_load_dt=20201115

If we try to limit to one end of the time window, it does not return the error.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, it couldn't consider the datetime as a column to be used in the where clause. Then, try this one.

```
select
    timestamp,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp / 1000) as datetime,
    subscription_name,
    path,
    value
from
    xx.xxxx
where
    subscription_name = 'xx_xx_xx'
    and path in (xxx)
    and DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp / 1000), '%Y-%m-%d')  > '2021-02-01'
```

Comment: It does not work and I believe the reason is the FROM_UNIXTIME() format is datetime but the string in front of is CHAR. So far, I have found the following band-aid that works with it giving me data after a certain date. But it does not let me narrow down the time window. Any ideas on how to make it narrow down based on date and time together? and FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp/1000) >= date('2021-03-05') Essentially, it seems like the FROM_UNTXTIME() output is a datatime format, and not a string format. So perhaps if we can convert the string to datetime format, the problem could be solved.Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So far, I have found the following band-aid that works with it giving me data after a certain date (But it does not let me narrow down the time window)"

`FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp/1000) >= date('2021-03-05')`

Essentially, it seems like the `FROM_UNTXTIME()` output is a datetime format, and not a string format.

So perhaps if we can convert the string to datetime format, the problem could be solved. Any ideas?